# how to get the images to slide in from right to left on an empty div?

Tags: jquery

how to get the images to slide in from right to left on an empty div? The code from this site almost do what I want http://jsfiddle.net/XjhEx/6/

The only requirement is how do I get the images to slide from right to left into an empty div upon a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `marginLeft: '100%'` instead of `marginLeft: '-100%'`.

http://jsfiddle.net/6jEtP/1/